# Button Click handler is not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-button

Directory structure of my activity is like below

[image]

That's why to get the button id, I wrote below code

```
View rootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_login, null, false);

btnLogin = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
```

But, due to some reasons, when I click button, it does not come inside hander. Am I missing something? My code is below.

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
});
```

**Complete code of Activity**

package com.example.pankajgarg.android.Activities.UserManagement.Auth.Login;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.pankajgarg.android.R;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnLogin;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        View rootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_login, null, false);

        btnLogin = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that all Java code must be in a method in a class. Please edit your question to show this.

Comment: Add a Toast /Log inside onClick and see if it gets called!

Comment: Also, you seem to have a Login**Activity**, so why are you inflating a Layout? That's done for Fragments.

Comment: without using inflate, I was unable to get the button memory and may be because of the directory structure?

Comment: are you calling `setContentView` in your activity?

Comment: I just added complete code of Activity. Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: You don't need the `getLayoutInflater().inflate(..)` line. Just call `setContentView(..)` after your `super.onCreate()`

Comment: @pztar can u please add a answer with updated activity code?

Comment: There are 2 answers here already that address that, but I've posted it anyways. Please make sure to include all relevant code next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way you can go about it is by using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)` in your `onCreate()` method and then pull the button with `findViewById(R.id.btnLogin)`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   //insert this line here
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

  //Pull the button with the id
  btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

  //set onclicklistener
  btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View view){
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `View rootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_login, null, false);` and replace it with `setContentView`

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnLogin;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in an Activity you don't need to inflate the layout, you are linking it with the `setContentView` method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
```

Secondly, if you want to do it the anonymous way you are ready to go, but add something to the onClick method:

```
btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // do whatever like...
        Log.d("MyActivity", "Click!");
        Toast.makeText(this, "Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
});
```

Or you can do it this way:

```
btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
```

If you do it this way you must implement the `View.OnClickListener` in your Activity with:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
     // Your Activity code
}
```

And finally, again, if you don't do anything in your click method Android won't do it, so:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // do whatever like...
    Log.d("MyActivity", "Click!");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

Comment: If you're calling `setOnClickListener(this)` then you don't need to call `setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())` as you'll already be overriding the `onClick()` method in your activity. Unless I'm incorrectly reading your answer.

Comment: Yes you are right, there are two ways, one in my answer and the anonymous way, like in the OP question

Comment: You should change the wording of your answer because as it reads it seems like you're suggesting both!

Comment: Yes, I have seen it now, i'm changing it,sorry!

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    View rootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_login, null, false);

    btnLogin = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
```

The line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);` inflates the layout and displays the views defined in your XML. These are completely different instances than those created by the previous call to `inflate()`. You seem to be mixing the way we inflate a view for a fragment and the way we do it for an activity. In Activities, we just call `setContentView()`. This means you should change your code to the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Now the code to set the `OnClickListener` will find the correct button.

Note that the first two lines of `onCreate()` will always be as shown here. The only difference will be the name of the layout used in `setContentView()`. You will avoid a lot of headache if you always follow this pattern.

Comment: I already have code in the handler. but I did not share the code. I could make sure that the handler was not invoked because I was using break point.

Comment: @PankajGarg in order to get the help you need, you should show the actual code you have that related to your question.  In this case the exact logic inside the listener is not relevant, but it held us to know that something is there. A comment to tell us that you intentionally left out the code is very appropriate.

Comment: @PankajGarg I edited my answer. It is very similar to others that beat me to the punch. The main difference is that I added an explanation of what you are doing wrong as well as the solution to fix it.

Comment: @PankajGarg sorry, that was a copy-paste error. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you did what @Code-Apprentice says (put something to execute), there are other things that can happen:

- Is the Button `clickable`? Check it in the layout or set it with

  `btnLogin.setClickable(true);`
- is the Button `enabled`? Same as before.
- is there an other `View` overlapping the button that catches the click before it?

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

it worked forme